# Explanation of the output obtained by using Macro

Tags: c, macros, printf

Why the second '%' is not printed ?

Also, why it is giving same output if I input `printf(scanf, scanf, scanf);`?

```
# include <stdio.h>
# define scanf  "%s Geeks Quiz "
int main()
{
printf(scanf, scanf);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> ***Why the second `%` is not printed ?***

Ans : Let's compare the `printf()` signature with your usage, shall we?

As per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf), the signature,

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

and your usage

```
printf(scanf, scanf);
```

Here,

- first `scanf` represents the `format` string, which includes the conversion specifier.
- second `scanf` is the argument corresponding to the first `%s` in the `printf()`.

In essence, your `printf()` looks like

```
printf("%s Geeks Quiz", "%s Geeks Quiz");
         ^              |-------------|
         |
    conversion           argument for %s
     specifier
```

So, as per the workings of `printf()`, the first `%s` is replaced by `%s Geeks Quiz`(here, `%s` is part of the output, not treated as a format specifier).

So, your final o/p looks like

```
%s Geeks Quiz  Geeks Quiz
```

> ***Also, why it is giving same output if I input `printf(scanf, scanf, scanf);?`***

Ans: `printf(scanf, scanf, scanf);`  will produce the same output as above, because, as per the `C11` standard, chapter 7.21.6.1, `fprintf()` function,

> If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess arguments are
> evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored.

As per the above explanation, we have only one format specifier `%s` (from the first `scanf` replacement) and one argument exactly is required for that. So, the third `scanf` is simply ignored.

Answer (score 2):

The macro expands to:

```
printf("%s Geeks Quiz ", "%s Geeks Quiz ");
```

where the first string is the print format string and the second string is a parameter passed into that string.

So the second string will put put into the place of %s of the first string:

```
 "%s Geeks Quiz "
 ^
 Insert second string "%s Geeks Quiz " here.

"%s Geeks Quiz  Geeks Quiz "
```

Answer (score 1):

Only the first string is the actual formatting string, it's the string that `printf` goes through to find formatting codes like `"%s"`. When it finds a formatting code it *replaces* it with the corresponding following argument.

So if the format string is `"%s Geeks Quiz "`, it will replace the `"%s"` with the first argument following the format-string, and if it's the same string then the output would be `"%s Geeks Quiz  Geeks Quiz "`.

If there are arguments that are not matched by a corresponding format code, then it's simply ignored.

Also, this has nothing to do with macros.